# What am I not understanding about Sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

So I have the following equation:

$$c(1)=6$$
$$c(n)=c(n-1)-16$$

-Find the third sequence-

The way I do it:
$$c(2)=6(2-1)-16 = -10$$
$$c(3)=-10(3-1)-16 = -36$$
What is it that I do wrong? Why is the correct answer: $$c(3) = -26$$

Comment: For $c(3)$, $-10-16=-26$

Comment: $c(n-1)$  isn't equal to $c(n-1) \cdot (n-1)$, right?

Comment: It might be helpful to change $c(n)$ to $c_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$c(n)$ is a function.  For any $n, c(n)$ has a particular value.  You are treating $c$ as a variable above, giving it meaning independent from its meaning as a function.

$c(1) = 6\\
c(2) = c(1) - 16 = 6-16 = -10\\
c(3) = c(2) - 16 = -10 - 16 = -26\\
c(4) = c(3) - 16 = -26 - 16 = -42$

You might be able to reason to a more general equation.

$c(n) = -16n + 22$

Comment: Hey Doug, thanks for your input. I'm still a little confused..  when you look at the function its $$c(n)=c(n-1)-16$$ Why is it that we don't take the "range" of this function going onward? Like why is it that we don't do: $$c(2)=6(2-1)-16$$ $$or$$ $$c(3)=6(3-1)-16$$

Comment: by range I actually meant output.. just to clarify. Fancy with the words.

Comment: I would just want to understand what part of this function tells us to use the last output as input for the next sequence. Obviously I know its a sequence but I wouldn't know without it being labeled as such.

Comment: $c(2) = c(2-1) - 16 = c(1)-16$ and $c(3) = c(3-1) - 16 = c(2)-16 = c(1) - 32$

Comment: $c(n)$ is a function that maps some set of numbers to some other set of numbers.  For any number $n$ and $c$ will map that $n$ somewhere else on the number line.

Answer (score 4):

$$c(2)=c(1)-16=6-16=-10$$

Then:

$$c(3)=c(2)-16=-10-16=-26$$

$c(n-1)$ is the function $c$ evaluated at $n-1$ not some number $c$ multiplied by $n-1$.